# Problems with adding a new delegate to a new controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to figure out how to take the delegate in LocationViewController and SetScoringTableViewController and implement both of them in GameDetailsTableViewController. LocationViewControllerDelegate was already working, but when I added the new SetScoringTableViewController, the program had an error.

LocationViewController.h

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@class LocationViewController;

 @protocol LocationViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)addItemViewController:(LocationViewController *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)name;

 @end

@interface LocationViewController : UIViewController
  @property (nonatomic, weak) id <LocationViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
    @end
```

SetScoringTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GameDetailsTableViewController.h"
#import "LocationViewController.h"

@class SetScoringTableViewController;

@protocol SetScoringTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)addItemViewControllerSS:(SetScoringTableViewController *)SScontroller didFinishEnteringItemSS:(NSString *)SSname;

@end

 @interface SetScoringTableViewController : UITableViewController
    @property (nonatomic, strong) id <SetScoringTableViewControllerDelegate> SSdelegate;

    @end
```

GameDetailsTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LocationViewController.h"
#import "SetScoringTableViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UITableViewController  <LocationViewControllerDelegate, SetScoringTableViewControllerDelegate>
```

When I run this I get an error: "Cannot find protocol declaration for 'SetScoringTableViewControllerDelegate' even though I have. 
The only way I have found to fix this problem is to put the "SetScoringTableViewController delegate in the LocationView Controller, but I know that is not right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're experiencing is an an `#import cycle`. To break the import loop
remove this import line:

```
#import "GameDetailsTableViewController.h"
```

from `SetScoringTableViewController.h` and put it in a `.m` file.

Answer (score 4):

You have a dependency loop:

SetScoringTableViewController.h

```
#import "GameDetailsTableViewController.h"
```

GameDetailsTableViewController.h

```
#import "SetScoringTableViewController.h"
```

But it looks like you can remove the `#import "GameDetailsTableViewController.h"` as there is no mention of it in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate the delegate on a different .h file.